# How can I update/replace an element of an XElement from a string?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

So here's my case.

I have an XElement, let's call it root, which has descendents, which have descendents, etc.  I pull a descendent using LINQ to XML, load it into a memo editor using `.ToString()` and edit it.  Now I want to update/replace the original descendent element with the edited version.

Let me mention that this is a simple XML file, with no schema, not using DOM, etc.  I only need to be able to edit and update/replace an element.

Here's a mockup of my XML:

```
<Root>
  <Genre Name="Rock">
    <Artist Name="Pink Floyd">
      <BandMembers>
        <Member>Nick Mason</Member>
        <Member>Syd Barret</Member>
        <Member>David Gilmour</Member>
        <Member>Roger Water</Member>
        <Member>Richard Wright</Member>
      </BandMembers>
      <Category>Favorite band of all time</Category>
    </Artist>
    <Artist Name="Led Zepelin">
      <Category>Love the band</Category>
    </Artist>
  </Genre>
  <Genre Name="Blues">
    <Artist Name="Muddy Waters">
      <Instrument>Harmonica</Instrument>
    </Artist>
    <Artist Name="Howling Wolf">
      <Instrument>Guitar</Instrument>
    </Artist>
  </Genre>
</Root>
```

Now say I want to edit "Pink Floyd" element to correct Roger Waters' last name.  I get that element, convert it to a string, load it into my editor, make the changes that I want, and convert it back to an XElement using `.Parse()`.

Now, how can I update/replace the "Pink Floyd" node in my original XML?

Comment: I updated your XML since it had some mismatched names and missing items. It's a valid structure but it's still not completely consistent, with Artsists occurring outside a Genre.

Comment: I updated the XML to put Muddy and Howling inside the Blues <Genre> tag. Now they're home! ;)

Comment: Oops!  That's what I get for free-handing the XML.  =)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use the [`XNode.ReplaceWith` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.replacewith):

```
// input would be your edited XML, this is just sample data to illustrate
string input = @"<Artist Name=""Pink Floyd"">
  <BandMembers>
    <Member>Nick Mason</Member>
    <Member>Syd Barret</Member>
    <Member>David Gilmour</Member>
    <Member>Roger Waters</Member>
    <Member>Richard Wright</Member>
  </BandMembers>
  <Category>Favorite band of all time</Category>
</Artist>";

var replacement = XElement.Parse(input);
var pinkFloyd = xml.Elements("Genre")
                   .Where(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "Rock")
                   .Elements("Artist")
                   .Single(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value == "Pink Floyd");

pinkFloyd.ReplaceWith(replacement);
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

You should add some error checking though. I used `Single` since I'm sure the node exists, but if there's a chance it isn't you should use `SingleOrDefault` and check for `null` before using the result.

Also, if the input is invalid you'll need to wrap the above code in a try/catch and handle any `XmlException` that might be thrown.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I don't know how I missed "ReplaceWith", since its named EXACTLY as the operation I wanted to perform.  And my app does check for XmlException when attempting to save the edited text.  Thanks.

Comment: In dotnet 4.7.2 (I haven't bothered checking elsewhere) there is no XElement.ReplaceWith but a [XNode.ReplaceWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode.replacewith?view=netframework-4.7.2). I don't dare update the answer as the URL looks so correct so to suggest there once has been a XElement.ReplaceWith.

Comment: In my case when I used `ReplaceWith` with a tag constructed from a string, I got an error `the parent is missing` because the `Parent` property of the new tag was not set. I fixed that by calling instead `originalNode.AddAfterSelf(newXNode); originalNode.Remove();`