# XElement.ReplaceWith throwing System.AccessViolationException

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml, access-violation, xelement

I'm working on an **WindowsPhone 8** app that stores and reads it's data from its *IsolatedStorage*.

***I'm using Visual Basic.NET and LINQ to XML.***

There's no problem with loading/saving the data, but I've got a serious issue with replacing an XElement with **[***XElementListName***].FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith([***NewXElementName***])**.

It throws an System.AccessViolationException, but only if it's supposed to find and replace the data bound to the **FIRST** item in a *LongListSelector*, also the first of that element in the XML file. Editing any other item works fine thou.
Here's the code from the routine that is supposed to replace the data.

```
Dim Accounts = From el In XMLData.<accounts>.<account> Where _
                   el.Attribute("title").Value = oiTitle And _
                   el.Attribute("uname").Value = oiName And _
                   el.Attribute("pass").Value = oiPass And _
                   el.Attribute("site").Value = oiSite And _
                   el.Attribute("description").Value = oiDesc _
                   Select el

    Dim acc As XElement = Accounts.FirstOrDefault()

    If acc.Equals(Nothing) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Error while saving edited account. Account not found.", "Account not found", MessageBoxButton.OK)
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim tmpstr As String = acc.Attribute("title").Value + _
                           acc.Attribute("uname").Value + _
                           acc.Attribute("pass").Value + _
                           acc.Attribute("site").Value + _
                           acc.Attribute("description").Value

    'Does this during debug to confirm that the replace is performed on the correct item.
    MessageBox.Show(tmpstr, "Info about first item", MessageBoxButton.OK)

    acc.Attribute("title").SetValue(NewInfo.Title)
    acc.Attribute("uname").SetValue(NewInfo.Username)
    acc.Attribute("pass").SetValue(NewInfo.Password)
    acc.Attribute("site").SetValue(NewInfo.Site)
    acc.Attribute("description").SetValue(NewInfo.Description)

    ' This code throws the exception when performing on the first item from the LongListSelector
    Accounts.FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(acc)
```

I've searched and tried to figure it out by looking at the LINQ to XML documentation, but it lacks usable examples. Also checked this: [How can I update/replace an element of an XElement from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820143/how-can-i-update-replace-an-element-of-an-xelement-from-a-string)

So, does anyone sit on any knowledge I could use to solve this?
If there's some code you'd like to see, just tell me, it's pretty ugly though.

**EDIT:** Omitted the *Accounts.FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(acc)* line, and it works just fine. Saves everything as it should. Also rewrote some code, here's the new one, and all the related code in that sub.

```
Public Sub EditAccount(ByVal OldInfo As AccountViewModel, ByVal NewInfo As AccountViewModel)
    Dim IsStore As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim File As New IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Open, IsStore)

    Dim XMLData As XElement = XElement.Load(File)

    Dim oiTitle As String = OldInfo.Title
    Dim oiName As String = OldInfo.Username
    Dim oiPass As String = OldInfo.Password
    Dim oiSite As String = OldInfo.Site
    Dim oiDesc As String = OldInfo.Description
    Try
        Dim Accounts = From e In XMLData.<accounts>.<account> Where ( _
                         e.Attribute("title").Value = oiTitle And _
                         e.Attribute("uname").Value = oiName And _
                         e.Attribute("pass").Value = oiPass And _
                         e.Attribute("site").Value = oiSite And _
                         e.Attribute("description").Value = oiDesc)
                     Select e Take 1

        Dim Account As XElement = Accounts.FirstOrDefault()

        If Account.Equals(Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error while saving edited account. Account not found.", "Account not found", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim tmpstr As String = Account.Attribute("title").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("uname").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("pass").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("site").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("description").Value

        'MessageBox.Show(tmpstr, "Info about first item", MessageBoxButton.OK)

        Account.Attribute("title").SetValue(NewInfo.Title)
        Account.Attribute("uname").SetValue(NewInfo.Username)
        Account.Attribute("pass").SetValue(NewInfo.Password)
        Account.Attribute("site").SetValue(NewInfo.Site)
        Account.Attribute("description").SetValue(NewInfo.Description)

        File.Close()
        IsStore.DeleteFile("Data.xml")
        File = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Create, IsStore)
        XMLData.Save(File)
        File.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Me.LoadData()
End Sub
```

Comment: `catch(Exception ex){ var thisIsWhatWeNeed = ex.ToString(); }` stack traces and inner exception details are always good.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. At: PassProFree.MainViewModel.EditAccount(AccountViewModel OldInfo, AccountViewModel NewInfo)

The weird thing is that it works if I select any other item in the LongList.

Comment: Looks like your problem lies elsewhere.  You should put a breakpoint where that is getting called and see who is null and why.

Comment: Actually, I commented out most of the code and rewrote some of it, and WITHOUT the ReplaceWith line, it does what it should. Kinda weird. Cause right after Accounts.FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(acc) I have the save code to save the edited XML.

Comment: BTW, your answer should go below in the answers selection.  That way you can select it as correct and close this out.  The alternatives would be for a vote to close this (which might hurt your account, you can read about auto post bans on [meta]), or delete it, which isn't much better.  The value here is that the inner exception was vastly different than the outer one (NRE is much different than an AVE, which is rare and indicates omgwtflol).

Comment: Will answer when I'm allowed to, a few hours until then xD Almost ready to deploy my app to Windows Phone 8 Store now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omitted the *Accounts.FirstOrDefault().ReplaceWith(acc)* line, and it works just fine. Saves everything as it should. Also rewrote some code, here's the new one, and all the related code in that sub.

```
Public Sub EditAccount(ByVal OldInfo As AccountViewModel, ByVal NewInfo As AccountViewModel)
    Dim IsStore As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    Dim File As New IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Open, IsStore)

    Dim XMLData As XElement = XElement.Load(File)

    Dim oiTitle As String = OldInfo.Title
    Dim oiName As String = OldInfo.Username
    Dim oiPass As String = OldInfo.Password
    Dim oiSite As String = OldInfo.Site
    Dim oiDesc As String = OldInfo.Description
    Try
        Dim Accounts = From e In XMLData.<accounts>.<account> Where ( _
                         e.Attribute("title").Value = oiTitle And _
                         e.Attribute("uname").Value = oiName And _
                         e.Attribute("pass").Value = oiPass And _
                         e.Attribute("site").Value = oiSite And _
                         e.Attribute("description").Value = oiDesc)
                     Select e Take 1

        Dim Account As XElement = Accounts.FirstOrDefault()

        If Account.Equals(Nothing) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error while saving edited account. Account not found.", "Account not found", MessageBoxButton.OK)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim tmpstr As String = Account.Attribute("title").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("uname").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("pass").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("site").Value + _
                               Account.Attribute("description").Value

        'MessageBox.Show(tmpstr, "Info about first item", MessageBoxButton.OK)

        Account.Attribute("title").SetValue(NewInfo.Title)
        Account.Attribute("uname").SetValue(NewInfo.Username)
        Account.Attribute("pass").SetValue(NewInfo.Password)
        Account.Attribute("site").SetValue(NewInfo.Site)
        Account.Attribute("description").SetValue(NewInfo.Description)

        File.Close()
        IsStore.DeleteFile("Data.xml")
        File = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Create, IsStore)
        XMLData.Save(File)
        File.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
    Me.LoadData()
End Sub
```